# Appropriate Birthday Message for Best Friend

Tags: friends, birthdays, friendship

So, one of my friend's birthday is coming up in a few days and I've bought a gift for her which has a little message as follows:

"No matter how many candles are on your birthday cake, **you sweeten up my life, you lighten up my world**"

I just wanted to know if this message is appropriate for a best friend, from whom I expect *nothing more than friendship*.

I do really mean it tho, as a friend, but wanted to get some confirmation about it being appropriate in terms of social convention etc.

Comment: General social conventions do not usually apply to best friends. You are one of the 2 only experts on this earth that know what is conventional in your friendship. The only way to get a useful answer is if your friend happens to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are best friends you will probably be right with your initial guess on on if she finds it appropriate or not. You are best friends for a reason =) and to that end I agree with @Raditz_35 comment. Stick with your gut feeling or hope she answers here.

Knowing nothing about your relationship I would be mainly concerned with the first part. Does she mind age references? Being ill-meaning I could read this as: "you are old as f*uck, but I like you anyway".

"you sweeten up my life" is okay. Unless she is extremely uneasy with compliments and reads "oh my god, he is sooo into me" into completely random looking things. But then again I see women denying that a best (guy) friend has a crush more then hoping/searching for it.

"you lighten up my life" is nothing out of the ordinary. You could write that to pretty much anybody as a birthday compliment.

So in summary, don't be too worried about it. You're probably fine.